# How do I iterate through the values of a row from a result set in java?

Tags: java, sql, jsp

The result set I'm speaking of this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

What I would like to do is this...

```
for row in rows
    for col in row
        //col is the name of the column, row[col] is the value.
```

I'm more profecient in PHP, than JSP, fyi. This would be done in PHP like so:

```
foreach($rs as $row)
    foreach($row as $col => $val)
        //val is the cell value, and column is the column name
```

EDIT: I'm looking for a generic solution. notice how col is a variable, not a literal.

Comment: While it is perfectly possible to read resultsets in JSP, that's not the right way to do it in Java. Such things should always be performed in a separate Java class whose result will be merely iterated in the JSP.

Comment: I appreciate the generic advice. I can assure you I would handle those details later... although honestly I'm hating every moment I'm programming in java.

Comment: No solution provided will not include the implicit statement, "you must learn something new".  If you are retrieving the resultSet using java, then loop through the resultSet, using java, and create something that is consumable in PHP, like a List of rows where each row is a list of columns.

Comment: You are correct, but I didn't get a generic answer until the horse dude gave one. I'm not afraid to learn something new, I simply prefer to keep things as simple as possible until my problem is solved. Now that it is, I can look into cleaner code matters such as tags that another person suggested.

Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is just a variation [the a_horse_with_no_name answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9009919/642706).
Here we use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of `List` objects as suggested there.

```
final ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
final int columnCount = meta.getColumnCount();
final List<List<String>> rowList = new LinkedList<List<String>>();
while (rs.next())
{
    final List<String> columnList = new LinkedList<String>();
    rowList.add(columnList);

    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; ++column) 
    {
        final Object value = rs.getObject(column);
        columnList.add(String.valueOf(value));
    }
}

// add the rowList to the request.
```

**Edit** Added final to all variables.

Answer (score 15):

```
ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
int colCount = meta.getColumnCount();
while (rs.next())
{
    for (int col=1; col <= colCount; col++) 
    {
        Object value = rs.getObject(col);
        if (value != null) 
        {
            System.out.print(value.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

But I would not recommend to do something like this directly in the JSP page. Build up some kind of value holder (e.g. a List of Lists) in the backend and iterate over that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will take your advice and use DwB's answer as I can throw that in a function.

I wish I could mark both your answers as the answer, but because I can't take my thanks and a feeling that you were the first to answer my question ;).

Answer (score 1):

It's easy if you use the [Java Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jstl-137486.html).

Check this out, too:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html

**I would strongly discourage you from embedding scriptlet code in your JSPs.  It's not the way to go.**

If you accept that, then every other answer given here has to be discarded.  They all belong in server-side Java classes, not a JSP.

Comment: I appreciate the link the the tag library, however is there not still a disconnect between getting the rows and columns into an array to be used with the foreach tag?

I have no idea how I would get my result set into such an array.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the mention of sql tags existing in the tutorial you mentioned.

Cool stuff.

Although I definitely appreciate your advice, I think a link to a tutorial using sql tags would have been more informative than only a link to a tags tutorial.

just constructive criticism. I truly do appreciate your suggestion!

Comment: Criticism?  Is Google not installed on your machine?  Don't you see the use of the SQL tag on the bottom of the very first page of the link that I gave to you?  And isn't that "Using JSTL" from Oracle, the source itself?  I don't think your criticism is at all constructive.  If I may, please put in a bit more effort in the future.  This isn't a spoon feeding site.

Comment: Why did I even ask the question? Why does anyone bother asking questions. Just google your problem and sift through APIs and documentations until you find the correct one and find what you're looking for.

I did some google searching. This link would have been more relevant:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html

Again, I wasn't insulting you. I truly appreciate your suggestion and you presented it in a good manner. I'm simply saying you could have been more direct. IMO constructive criticism.

Comment: Next time let me know what size spoon you'd like to be fed with.  That's the link I sent you, just three pages down.  You have to put in some effort, too.

Comment: 3 pages down...

Do me a favor, don't ever write a UI. Less people suffer from the inconvenience of your UX knowledge.

EDIT: I'm starting to get a bit hostile. Keep in mind, I still highly respect the attention you give to people on this website. Keep up noble work =).

Comment: Fair enough, Jason.  Good luck with JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to read through [The Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) first.

```
while(rs.next()) {
    String col1 = rs.getString("NAME"); // if NAME is VARCHAR2, for eg.
}
```

While it is perfectly possible to read resultsets in JSP, that's not the right way to do it in Java. Such things should always be performed in a separate Java class whose result will be merely iterated in the JSP.

Comment: This Answer does *not* address the Question, which asks for a generic way to handle the columns without specifying each column and its data type.