# Java ResultSet metadata get columnName is throwing out of bounds at index 4 when the column count is 13

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, resultset

Looping through a REsult set with a column count of 13(verified) throws an index out of range at index 4.

```
    int total_colunms = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    System.out.println("Count: " +rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount()+"");
    for(int i = 1; i <=total_colunms; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    jPlayer.addProperty(rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i).toLowerCase(),rs.getObject(i).toString());
```

The Logs

```
Count: 13
1
2
3
java.sql.SQLException: Column index out of range.
   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData.getField(ResultSetMetaData.java:395)
   at        com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName(ResultSetMetaData.java:243)
at com.amazonaws.lambda.scores_dbo.GetPlayerFunctionHandler.parseJsonString(GetPlayerFunctionHandler.java:33)
at com.amazonaws.lambda.scores_dbo.GetPlayerFunctionHandler.handleRequest(GetPlayerFunctionHandler.java:18)
at com.amazonaws.lambda.scores_dbo.GetPlayerFunctionHandler.handleRequest(GetPlayerFunctionHandler.java:1)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:178)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:888)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:281)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:64)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:94)
enter code here
```

Comment: Is res.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i) failing or is rs.getObject(i) ?

Comment: getColumnLabel, 
Ive also tried getColumnName

Comment: Check how this loops through the resultset and see if it will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009422/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-values-of-a-row-from-a-result-set-in-java

Comment: Seems like a bit of a long shot, but do you know what version of mysql jdbc driver you're using?  Looks like they had a problem that could be related: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84084

Comment: And can you update the code snippet?  The for loop doesn't close...